# Java + TomEE. Websockets and Servlets in one project?

Tags: java, sockets, servlets, apache-tomee

I'm writing a simple game with JavaEE Websocket technology. Using JSR356, my server-side socket class looks like following:

```
@ServerEndpoint(
    value = "/sock",    
    decoders = { SocketDecoder.class }
)
public class CardsSocket {
    ....
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(final SocketInput message, final Session session) {
        ...
    }
    ... 
}
```

It works perfectly fine, and has no issues. But then I decided to create also some web page for info and stuff. So, without changing anything on previous class, I have created a new one:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/cards")
public class CardsWebPage extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And configured web.xml file in WEB-INF directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1"
  metadata-complete="true">

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>CardsWebPage</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>server.CardsWebPage</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CardsWebPage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cards</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And there began troubles. My servelet works - browser shows page on localhost:8080/cards, but client-side socket class can no longer initiate - it falls with Exception:

```
"javax.websocket.DeploymentException: The HTTP response from the server [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found] did not permit the HTTP upgrade to WebSocket"
```

, and nothing seems to fix it. Have I missed some documentation? Is it impossible for a single project to contain both servlets and websocket classes? Because, if I delete web.xml file, then sockets are starting to work like before. Server startup logs containing no warnings or errors in both cases.

Comment: Why do you want this in a single project? You can deploy multiple projects to a single server (different ports) which might work better. I don't know the finer details of this, but it sounds like you are trying to make two separate types of servlets inside the same project, which could cause serious issues.

Comment: I don't think the serbletclass should carry the websocket specific @serverendpoint annotation. Not sure if removing that would fix anything

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, perhaps sparks is right, and I should simply deploy multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

Hi why decorating CardsWebPage with @ServerEndpoint? Nothing or if you can to get rid of web.xml @WebServlet should be fine.